# Will my progress be saved if I uninstall a digital game from my PS4?

Tags: ps4

I digitally downloaded a game on my PS4. If I choose to uninstall it to free up space, will my progress will be saved and available if I choose to reinstall it at some point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you delete a game from your PS4, you will have access to your old save file whenever you choose to reinstall it.

I recently reinstalled God Eater 2 after playing nearly a year ago and my save file was accessible (though I opted to create a new file, because I did not remember where I was in the story).

Comment: In many cases, I've found that most of my saves are on the Playstation Network Cloud as well.

Comment: Of course, this assumes you don't go deleting stuff from your save data folders.